# Hyperledger Blockchain Writing your first application fabcar

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to go through the Writing your first application tutorial located at:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html
I make it the majority of the way through and can run enrollAdmin.js with no issues. However, when I try to run registerUser.js I get the following error:
Failed to register user "user1": TypeError: gateway.getClient is not a function

I have done extensive google searches but cannot find any related solutions. Here is the code for the registerUser.js

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
/*
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const { Gateway, Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'first-network', 'connection-org1.json');

async function main() {
    try {

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userIdentity = await wallet.get('user1');
        if (userIdentity) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "user1" already exists in the wallet');
            return;
        }

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
        const adminIdentity = await wallet.get('admin');
        if (!adminIdentity) {
            console.log('An identity for the admin user "admin" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the enrollAdmin.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'admin', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

        // Get the CA client object from the gateway for interacting with the CA.
        const client = gateway.getClient();
        const ca = client.getCertificateAuthority();

        const adminUser = await client.getUserContext('admin', false);

        // Register the user, enroll the user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
        const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: 'org1.department1', enrollmentID: 'user1', role: 'client' }, adminUser);
        const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'user1', enrollmentSecret: secret });
        const x509Identity = {
            credentials: {
                certificate: enrollment.certificate,
                privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
            },
            mspId: 'Org1MSP',
            type: 'X.509',
        };
        await wallet.put('user1', x509Identity);
        console.log('Successfully registered and enrolled admin user "user1" and imported it into the wallet');

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to register user "user1": ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: Currently the fabric-node-sdk is changing as a 2.0 version has not been released as of yet and the samples (master branch) are not upto date with the beta changes of the node-sdk. However as you are trying to follow fabric 1.4 then I suggest changing the branch of your fabric-samples clone from master to 1.4

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. did you manage to register the user in 2.0?

Comment: Yeah I did, using the above suggestion. Switched the branch of my fabric-sample clone fixed the issue.